# I need these scripts to work script valid and the other calculates

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

This example is included in the bootstrap documentation. I need both scripts to work. The first validates the data in all the fields and the second part calculates the data. However, only the second works. I need both scripts to work.

```html
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="validationCustom01">First name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" required>
            <div class="valid-feedback">
                Looks good!
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="validationCustom02">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom02" required>
            <div class="valid-feedback">
                Looks good!
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="validationCustom03">City</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom03" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Please provide a valid city.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="other();return false;" id="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>

<div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
    <label for="result">TEXT RESULT</label>
    <textarea rows="3" id="result" ></textarea>
</div>

<script>
    function other() {

        // SCRIPT 1   START - THIS SCRIPT DOES NOT WORK WHY?
        (function() {
            'use strict';
            window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
                var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
                // Loop over them and prevent submission
                var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
                    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            event.stopPropagation();
                            alert(" this does not work ");
                        }
                        form.classList.add('was-validated');
                    }, false);
                });
            }, false);
        })();
// END - THIS SCRIPT DOES NOT WORK WHY?

// SCRIPT2 THIS WORK
        let s1 = document.querySelector('#validationCustom01').value;
        let s2 = document.querySelector('#validationCustom02').value;
        let s3 = document.querySelector('#validationCustom03').value;

        concat =  s1 + s2 + s3;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = concat;
    }
</script>
```

Thanks for the quick reply, But still not working well.
The goal is to show concat in the textarea id result without erasing the old data.
The goal is to display concat in the textarea id result without erasing the old data.

Currently if I fill in all the fields and click submit, the concat is not seen in TEXTAREA id result. It is as if all the data is lost.
The objective is to have the fields filled, when clicking submit the concat must be calculated and displayed in TEXTAREA, all the fields must keep their values.
Otherwise (for example, an empty field) indicate field filling errors.

Comment: what is the point to have an IIFE inside `function other()` ? (where load event will never append)

Comment: this is only one example. The objective is that the fields are filled, when clicking on submit the concat must be calculated and displayed in TEXTAREA, all the fields must keep their values.
Otherwise (for example, an empty field) indicates field fill errors.

Comment: since HTML5 you can use attribute `required` on inputs and form validation mecanisms